# How do i show only one form at a time when i reload the page and didn't check one of the radio button in Laravel 6.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

***I have two forms in one view, if you checked one of the `radiobutton` shows you only the one you want it, the problem is when you reload the page and you didnt check any of the radiobutton's shows you both forms, i tried putting `check` to one of the radio's but didnt work to, still shows me both forms, how can i solve the problem***

- Below i will let the code of my `radiobutton` and the `script` in jQuery that shows you the form you want it when you select one

***Code of the `radiobutton`***

```html
<input type="radio" id="admin" value="administrador" name="tipo" >
                  <label for="admin">Admin</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="cliente" value="cliente" name="tipo">
                  <label for="natural">Cliente</label>
```

***Code of the `script` in jQuery***

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:radio[id=admin]').attr('checked',true);
        $("#admin").on( "click", function() {
            $('#email_1').show(); //muestro mediante id
            $('#password_1').show();
            $('#email_2').hide();
            $('#password_2').hide();
        });
        $("#cliente").on( "click", function() {
          $('#email_1').hide(); //oculto mediante id
          $('#password_1').hide();
          $('#email_2').show();
          $('#password_2').show();
        });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the `HTML`  of both forms? I don't know why your don't have one form with email/password but then use the `radio` button value to define admin or *"Cliente"*. If you really had this setup correctly then you wouldn't need to give that option and the server-side could define *"Cliente"* to *"Admin"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for someone to click a button to hide the second form, make sure its hidden by default and also when the radio is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:radio[id=admin]').attr('checked',true);
            $('#email_2').hide(); // Add this
            $('#password_2').hide();  // and this
        $("#admin").on( "click", function() {
            $('#email_1').show(); //muestro mediante id
            $('#password_1').show();
            $('#email_2').hide();
            $('#password_2').hide();
        });
        $("#cliente").on( "click", function() {
          $('#email_1').hide(); //oculto mediante id
          $('#password_1').hide();
          $('#email_2').show();
          $('#password_2').show();
        });
      });
      </script>
```